# Why can't I get Java ProcessBuilder to execute in my windows 10 computer?

Tags: java, windows, processbuilder

I have a problem to execute a Windows program with Processbuilder.
The code below results in a command array like:

`C:\\Program Files\\Gdal\\bin\\gdal\\apps\\gdalwarp.exe, -t_srs, EPSG:32633, -et, 1, -r, near, H:\\GeoData\\Raster\\1M_WEF30JAN2020_WGS84LL_somlos_8.tif, H:\\GeoData\\Raster\\result.tif`

```
String [] cmd = {"C:\\Program Files\\Gdal\\bin\\gdal\\apps\\gdalwarp.exe",
  "-t_srs",  "EPSG:" + txtEPSG.getText(), 
  "-et", txtThreshold.getText().trim(),
  "-r", cmbBoxResampl.getSelectedItem().toString(),
  txtInFilename.getText(),
  txtNewFilename.getText()
};
boolean r = Files.isExecutable(new File("C:\\Program Files\\Gdal\\bin\\gdal\\apps\\gdalwarp.exe").toPath());
java.lang.ProcessBuilder b = new java.lang.ProcessBuilder(cmd);
b.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
b.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
Map<String,String> map = b.environment();
Process p = b.start();
int rc = p.waitFor();
if (p.exitValue() != 0) {
  System.out.println(p.exitValue());
  System.out.println("Command: " + cmd[0]);
  InputStream errorStream = p.getErrorStream();
  int c = 0;
  while ((c = errorStream.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.print((char)c);
 }
}
```

And when I debug the java program I can see that the gdalwarp.exe is executable and that the environment settings is the same as when I execute gdalwarp.exe in a cmd-terminal.
The processBuilder seems not to execute gdalwarp. The exit code I get is -1073741511, it should be 0 or -1.
The errorStream is empty, and I get no out prints.

When I execute
`C:\Program Files\Gdal\bin\gdal\apps\gdalwarp.exe -t_srs EPSG:32633 -et 1 -r near H:\GeoData\Raster\1M_WEF30JAN2020_WGS84LL_somlos_8.tif H:\GeoData\Raster\result.tif`
in a cmd-terminal, I get outprints that make sense and a resulting file: H:\GeoData\Raster\result.tif.

I've tried with and without the path to gdalwarp.exe, but it is only in the cmd-terminal that it works.
Any ideas?

When I execute cmd.exe with the ProcessBuilder I get outprints that make sense.

**--Update----**

When I add printouts for exit code, isExecutable, env.variables in the program I got this:

`Command: C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\apps\gdalwarp.exe, -t_srs, EPSG:32633, -et, 1, -r, near, C:\Temp\1M_WEF30JAN2020_WGS84LL_somlos_8_overview.tif, C:\Temp\1M_WEF30JAN2020_8_overview.tif`

`C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\apps\gdalwarp.exe is exacutable`

`Exit value:-1073741511`

**A selection of process.env.variables:**

`PROCESSOR_LEVEL, 6`

`JAVA_HOME, C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-8.0.262.10-hotspot\jre`

`POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS, GTiff PNG JPEG GIF XYZ DTED USGSDEM AAIGrid`

`GDAL_DATA, C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal-data`

`GDAL_DRIVER_PATH, C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\plugins;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\plugins-external`

`PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE, AMD64`

`PSModulePath, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`

`SystemDrive, C:`

`POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS, 1`

`ProgramFiles(x86), C:\Program Files (x86)`

`CommonProgramFiles, C:\Program Files\Common Files`

`Path, C:/Users/anpaumal/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/anpaumal/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932/jre/bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Python\Python39\;C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-8.0.262.10-hotspot\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\python\osgeo;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\proj6\apps;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\apps;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\ms\apps;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\csharp;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\curl;C:\Users\anpaumal\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\eclipse;`

`PATHEXT, .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`

`DriverData, C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData`

`OS, Windows_NT`

`PROJ_LIB, C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\proj7\SHARE`

`PROCESSOR_REVISION, 9e0d`

`CommonProgramW6432, C:\Program Files\Common Files`

`ProgramData, C:\ProgramData`

`ProgramW6432, C:\Program Files`

`CommonProgramFiles(x86), C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files`

`ProgramFiles, C:\Program Files`

**And a selection of settings from system environment:**

`ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData`

`CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files`

`CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files`

`CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files`

`DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData`

`GDAL_DATA=C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal-data`

`GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\plugins;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\plugins-external;`

`JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-8.0.262.10-hotspot\jre`

`NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=12`

`OS=Windows_NT`

`Path=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Python\Python39\;C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-8.0.262.10-hotspot\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\python\osgeo;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\proj6\apps;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\apps;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\ms\apps;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\gdal\csharp;C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\curl;C:\Users\anpaumal\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;`

`PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`

`ProgramData=C:\ProgramData`

`ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files`

`ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)`

`ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files`

`PROJ_LIB=C:\Program Files\Gdal_321\bin\proj7\SHARE`

`PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`

Comment: Why do you have twice the line "b.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);" ?

Comment: One is for input and the other one is for error.

Comment: Simplify your command.  Just see if the gdalwarp.exe executes with no parameters.  Then add one parameter at a time until you see which parameter is causing the problem.

Comment: I have tried that, in the cmd-terminal gdalwarp prints out help instructions when there is no arguments. In processBuilder the streams are empty and it seems like gdalwarp is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the output before calling `p.waitFor()` with:

```
List<String> results = readOutput(process.getInputStream());
```

And possibly print those results out to check.

Comment: Have done that now, but the stream is still empty :-(

Answer (score 0):

If I add working directoy it works!

```
ProcessBuilder b = new java.lang.ProcessBuilder(cmd);
File f = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Gdal_321\\bin\\gdal\\apps");
b.directory(f);
Process p = b.start();
```

Comment: oh nice, what a gotcha